# Unable Run Python On Visual Studio Code

Tags: python

May please assist to check is there anything work for runing code?

Sine i was new to learning Python coding and i do setup Visual Studio Code. After that I'm testing to run and then I'm stacking here now.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKsCo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format to run python program is:

```
python Hello.py
```

For your case.